# How to convert the image to css3 gradient?

Tags: css

Since http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ is not working any more, is there anything that can help to convert image into css3 gradient? http://prntscr.com/bonecv

I already checked with few sites like:

- http://gradientfinder.com/
- http://www.gradient-scanner.com/

but nothing worked for me.

Comment: since when is it not working any more? Works for me....

Comment: What exactly is your problem, if you're seeing issues with multiple site then it's very probably your own system or method that is not working. What are you trying to achieve? what are you doing to achieve it? And how is this currently failing? don't comment but **EDIT YOUR QUESTION.**. Thanks.

Comment: Colorzilla is definitely working.

Comment: @Martin i mean those other sites didn't work for me as colorzilla did. so you mean colorzilla gradient editor is working for you? it's been a while, the site won't load here

Comment: The site you link to on your question works and loads.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bonecv doesn't work for me :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for off-site suggestions as an alternative to a site that is confirmed as working. Furthermore, the actual problem to be solved was never presented - i.e How to make css3 gradient from an image.

Comment: @enhzflep i don't know if the problem is for our country, i also posted the screenshot showing the site not working

Comment: @Lucian - a site which can help when wondering if an outage is local or global is: http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/ - Why don't you post the image and your efforts to create a gradient for it? Or, is this question merely seeking to find another online tool as an alternative?

Comment: @enhzflep thank you for the site you provided. it shows the site is up and maybe it's just for me it's down. i am seeking to find another online tool as an alternative so that i can use it later as well

Comment: @Lucian - You're welcome. Pssst! Dont (ask here for another online tool) That puts the question firmly in the realms of being off-topic. (Asking for offsite resources makes the question off-topic - see the help center). This is why I made reference a couple of times to the actual gradient you're trying to create. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116389/discussion-between-lucian-and-enhzflep).

Comment: @Lucian thank you for the screenshot, you can use colorzilla in firefox (and probably other browsers) by downloading the Colorzilla app/plugin (when the site works for you or from the Firefox plugin store (free)) and then you can use it as part of your browser, even if the website is offline. Good luck